# Calling SVNKit from Clojure

Tags: clojure, svnkit

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://wiki.svnkit.com/Printing_Out_A_Subversion_Repository_Tree) for using svnkit, but doing it from clojure. My code is:

```
(defn svntest [ url ]
  (. DAVRepositoryFactory setup)
  (try (let [ repository (. SVNRepositoryFactory create 
           (. SVNURL parseURIEncoded url))]    
           (.iterator 
              (. repository getDir "svnkit" -1 nil (cast Collection nil)))
         )
    (catch SVNException svne
      (println (str "err: " (.getMessage svne)))
      )
  )
)
(svntest "http://svn.svnkit.com/repos/svnkit/trunk")
```

However, my `getDir` call doesn't seem to work - I get an IllegalArgumentException because this getDir is returning a long rather than a collection.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to cast the arguments in a different way to get another version of this overloaded method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this type hint the collection in the `let` statement as so:

```
(let [^Collection coll nil
      repository (. SVNRepositoryFactory create 
                   (. SVNURL parseURIEncoded url))]
        (.iterator
          (. repository getDir "svnkit" -1 nil coll)))
; ...
```